# FFMPEG - Padding bottom of image

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg (in batch file), Is it possible to add whitespace (padding) to the bottom of an image if it is less than 720px in height?
If the image is 720px or more, do nothing.

Basically, the image should be a minimum of 720px.

I've tried scale and crop but I don't really have a lot of experience so need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) filter with [`max`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation):

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "pad=w=iw:h='max(720,ih)':x=0:y=0:color=white" output
```